# convert date with time formats [R]

Tags: r, lubridate

how can i convert a date from a format like **yyyymmdd H:M** to **yyyy-mm-dd H:M**, basicaly from **20200101 00:00** to **2020-01-01 00:00**. i have tried multiple as.Date formats and cant obtain the result i want

example of what i have :

```
dates <- c("20200101 00:00", "20200101 01:00")
want <- as.Date(have, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M")
```

the output:

```
> want<- as.Date(dates, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M")
> want
[1] "2020-03-01" "2020-03-01"
```

Comment: When you use `as.Date`, you don't get a time (a Date object has no time). Try `want <- as.POSIXct(dates, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M")`

Comment: Or, as you have tagged `lubridate`, you can use `as_datetime()`

Answer (score 0):

There's two pieces here. One is converting to date time class, such as POSIXt. Then there is how this object is printed. Under the hood it's all represented the same, but you can control how it's displayed.

The `format` argument in any of the conversion functions (`as.Date` or `as_datetime`) is describing how to parse the string representation into the components of a data time object (e.g. where in the string to find the minutes). You need to then use something like `format` or `strftime` to then control how the values are printed/displayed.

Below is what I think you're aiming for:

```r
dates_as_strings <- c("20200101 00:00", "20200101 01:00")
dates_as_datetime_objs <- lubridate::as_datetime(dates_as_strings, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M")

strftime(dates_as_datetime_objs, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
#> [1] "2020-01-01 00:00" "2020-01-01 01:00"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>